# How to check internet connection using javascript and asyn functioon?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, connection

I found this sample code in the following websites:

- [github](https://gist.github.com/gitdagray/f310be81be217750fc9d2b233e2ae70c)
- [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-check-internet-connection-status-with-javascript/)

to help determine the connection status between client side and the internet.

```
const checkOnlineStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const online = await fetch("/1pixel.png");
      return online.status >= 200 && online.status < 300; // either true or false
    } catch (err) {
      return false; // definitely offline
    }
  };
  
  setInterval(async () => {
    const result = await checkOnlineStatus();
    const statusDisplay = document.getElementById("status");
    statusDisplay.textContent = result ? "Online" : "OFFline";
  }, 3000); // probably too often, try 30000 for every 30 seconds
  
  // forgot to include async load event listener in the video! 
  window.addEventListener("load", async (event) => {
    const statusDisplay = document.getElementById("status");
    statusDisplay.textContent = (await checkOnlineStatus())
      ? "Online"
      : "OFFline";
  });
```

However this seems to produce an error in the console when running it. The error is:

```
script.js:6 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/1pixel.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Does anyone else get this same error or know how to get around this?

**Edit:** I got the solution by changing the fetch API call to this:

```
const online = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
```

Probably the error was caused by the previous fetch API not correctly working

Comment: Regardless if you catch a 404 error, the browser is still going to log it..  Maybe an alternative -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: Navigator.online will produce a boolean TRUE value if the system is connected to any network regardless of its the internet or not. 
For example if its connected to other systems with LAN it'll still give a false positive value. Therefore it'll not tell me about the connection status with the internet

Comment: Another idea, and is the way I detect offline mode is by using webSockets,.  When the app first starts I create a websocket connection, if I detect a disconnect, I know I'm offline.

Comment: `404 Not Found` may indicate that you are trying to access a URL that does not exist, or maybe `1pixel.png` does not exist? Can you check it?

Comment: Yeah i checked, you are right, the 1pixel.png doesnt exist. 
So i had to change that and it worked!